# Restore a minimized window of another application (C++ WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on a C++ program that which launches a .NET Winforms application.

If the app is already running, I want to restore the window instead. I grab the .NET app's window handle and use SetForegroundWindow() to bring to to the front.

This works except when the application is minimized.

I've tried combinations of the following:

```
ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
```

and

```
SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
```

However, when this code is executed, the event becomes stuck. In the tray I see `".NET-BroadcastEventWindow.2.0.0.0.378734a.0"` come up as a second window in the tray along with my .NET app, and the app is never restored properly.

This only happens when I try to send a `SW/SC_RESTORE` or `SHOW` event. `SetForegroundWindow()` has no issues.

Has anyone else seen this problem before?

Comment: Windows has implemented significant measures to prevent focus-stealing (both for usability - users get annoyed by spontaneous focus changes - and for security - typing a password into a chat window that popped up over your login box would be bad). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past that I've solved using Get/SetWindowPlacement():

```
// Ensure that the given window is not minimized.
// If it is minimized, restore it to its normal state.
void EnsureNotMinimized(HWND hWnd)
{
   WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
   placement.length = sizeof(placement);

   if(!GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &placement))
      return;

   BOOL minimized = (placement.showCmd & SW_SHOWMINIMIZED) != 0;
   if(!minimized)
      return;

   placement.showCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &placement);
}
```

However, I've only used this for windows that belong to my own application. I don't know if security would allow it to be used on outsiders.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that this will not work across processes for the reasons explained in my link, but I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Aaaaaand it actually worked.